# Rails javascript files document ready seem to be overwriting one another

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

If my application.js looks like

```
//= require file1
//= require file3
//= require file3
//= require file4
```

and each of my file#.js contain a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // set click events and other cool stuff
}
```

It seems like only file1 gets set.  Is it better practice to have only 1 .js file that calls document ready on a bunch of other .js file methods? I am not using turbolinks or tree, is that part of the issue?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this. You can use as many `$(document).ready` callbacks as you want, and they will not over-write each other. You'll have to look at how your files are being included and do some debugging, we can't help with what you've posted here.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have an error on one of the first javascript files, the others will still render, but will not run. Inspect your page and see if you have any JS errors.

Answer (score 0):

Solution which works pretty good is to add conditional check after $(document).ready to check whether the html class is assigned for particular javascript.

This is my coffeescript example:

```
ready = () ->
  if $('body').hasClass 'landing'
    ....

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```